# Find a formula for $f(x, y)$ given the following assumptions...?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I've been going through some examples in my textbook ready for a uni exam in a few days, and I am having difficulty with a few of the questions, in particular this one:

> A gene is a sequence of DNA that encodes either protein or RNA
>   molecules that may inhibit or excite the expression of other genes. A
>   genetic circuit is a collection of genes which interact in this way.
>   Suppose two gene cells, A and B inhibit each other’s expression. Let x
>   and y denote the concentrations of two proteins encoded by the genes A
>   and B respectively. Let $f(x, y)$ be the rate of change of the
>   concentration of protein A.
>
> (a) Find a formula for $f(x, y)$,
>   given the following assumptions:
>
> i. f(x, y) is the difference between
>   the rate at which gene A produces protein A and the rate at which
>   protein A degrades.
>
> ii. The concentration of protein A degrades at a
>   rate equal to its concentration.
>
> iii. Gene A produces protein A at a
>   rate inversely proportional to $1 + y$.
>
> iv. Gene A produces protein A at
>   a constant rate 3 when protein B is absent.

If someone wouldnt mind giving a few pointers, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think it goes something like this

x and y are concentrations

$iii)$ gene A produces protein A at rate $\frac{1}{1+y}$

$ii)$ A degrades at rate x

$i)$ $f(x,y)$ is difference between production and degradation rate  so $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+y}-x$

$iv)$  i guess when B is absent its concentration is $0$ ($y=0$) so $f(x,0)=3-x$

( production is 3 and i guess degradation remains x, as in $ii)$)

so final answer could be 
$$  f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
 \frac{1}{1+y}-x & \text{for $y\ne 0$} \\   
 3-x &\text{for y=0} 
\end{cases}$$